# Yii - how to make url as readable?

Tags: php, url, yii

I am creating a realestate website, I want my url to be readable,

For example my site url is `http://sitename/property/3`, (3 represents property id)

I want to change it like this [link](http://www.99acres.com/Residential-Apartment-Flat-in-Park-View-City-Gurgaon-4-BHK-for-Sale-spid-H13544257&pos=SEARCH?sid=UiB8IFFTIHwgUyB8IzcjICB8IENQMzIgIzE2I3wgIHwgQ1BfUiB8IDMyICMyI3wgIHwgMTM1NDQyNTcsODc5NDA0NyB8IDEgfCA4ICMxI3wgIHwgTyxCLEEgfCMyIyAgfCAxICM0I3wgIHwgTyxCLEEgfCMxNiMgIHwgTlAsUjJNIHwjNiMgIHw=)

My question is how they are using "Residential-Apartment-Flat-in-Park-View-City-Gurgaon-4-BHK-for-Sale-spid-H13544257" this part in url.

Of course they are using id and all. How can I replace "property" with something like "residential-property-in-india" in my url and it should be changing dynamically according to search.

I hope it is clear what I want to do...

Comment: Do you want an URL which looks like this: www.example.com/arg0/value0/arg1/value1/... ?

Comment: Instead of using numerical primary key they use a string primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is in the [Yii guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.url)

For example the folling urls config in the url manager component

```
array(
    'posts'=>'post/list',
    'post/<id:\d+>'=>'post/read',
    'post/<year:\d{4}>/<title>'=>'post/read',
)
```

Will generate link like http://example.com/post/2004/My-title-that-can-be-long

You can tweak it to match your need,if I were you I'll read the Yii guide very carfully

Comment: I am trying to use something like this array( '<title>/search'=> 'search') but its not working whether its correct or wrong?

Comment: Maybe the order of your rules is wrong. The order must be from the most restrictive one to the least.
For example if you have a rule <controller>/<action> before the rule you are trying to use, then this rule will be use and will throw a 404.

Answer (score 0):

At the last of rules array place this rule

```
'<page>'=>'someControlles/someAction',
```

And you will get in someControlles/someAction parameter. $page = 'any_text'. Another way to create your own [UrlRule](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUrlRule).